# Remove Duplicates from Sorted List

Tags: java, algorithm

For example:

- Given 1→1→2, return 1→2.
- Given 1→1→2→3→3, return 1→2→3.

My question is why the returned object is `head` but not `node`? And Why `node.next` means the node traversal moves to next node ? I am confused:

```
public class Solution {
    public ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
        if(head == null)
            return null;
        ListNode node = head;
        while(node.next != null) {
            if(node.val == node.next.val) {
                node.next = node.next.next;
            } else {
                node = node.next;

            }
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note this implementation only supports duplicates that are next to each other in the list

Comment: deleteDuplicates() returns the head because from the head you can access the whole list. From any other node you might not be able to (unless it's a doubly-linked list), but even if you could, it's easiest to work with the list if you know where your starting point is.

Comment: @GregHilston: If it's a sorted list, then duplicates have to be next to each other, don't they?

Comment: You are correct, I misread and overlooked that we are working with a sorted list. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help understand, I'll suffix the values with letters to see the different instances, e.g. if original list is 1→1→1→2→2→3→3, that would then be 1a→1b→1c→2a→2b→3a→3b

The goal is to remove duplicates, and it progresses as follows:

Start at head: `node = head`

```
↓
1a→1b→1c→2a→2b→3a→3b
```

Remove 1b: `node.next = node.next.next`

```
↓
1a→1c→2a→2b→3a→3b
```

Remove 1c: `node.next = node.next.next`

```
↓
1a→2a→2b→3a→3b
```

Move forward: `node = node.next`

```
   ↓
1a→2a→2b→3a→3b
```

Remove 2b: `node.next = node.next.next`

```
   ↓
1a→2a→3a→3b
```

Move forward: `node = node.next`

```
      ↓
1a→2a→3a→3b
```

Remove 3b: `node.next = node.next.next`

```
      ↓
1a→2a→3a
```

Exit loop: `node.next != null`
Return updated list: `head`

```
↓
1a→2a→3a
```

As you can see, `node.next = node.next.next` doesn't actually move you forward, but to does progress you a step further to your goal.

You have to return `head`, otherwise you'd just return the last node, i.e.

```
↓
3a
```

and you don't want that.

Comment: thanks for so much details of explanation.  The head and the node are defined as ListNode type means they need to point to the Class memory place or some other purpose? next represents the next node and can move to "next"  memory position of the list? Thanks

Comment: @HelenWang Not fully understanding your comment. After `node = head`, the `node` variable references node "1a", as represented by the ↓ arrow. Node "1a" has value `1`, and `node.next` is represented by the → arrow between node "1a" and node "1b", i.e. the object *referenced* by `node.next` is node "1b", which also has a value of `1`. `node.next.next` is represented by the → arrow between node "1b" and node "1c", i.e. the object *referenced* by `node.next.next` is node "1c". The code `node.next = node.next.next` then updates "1a" to reference "1c" instead of "1b".

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a list; lists are represented by the head node.  As for the bit about node.next: because that is what it is designed to do.